# Using a cursor for loop

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, cursor

I encounter a following code syntax in sql but not able to figure out why it is written.

```
select distinct tbl.sample_key,ctr.sample_value 
      from tablename tbl where  tbl.Sample_id=CID.sample_id
```

where CID is the for loop counter variable

```
for CID in (----)
```

please help me to understand as I am new to this why do we use this? 
what is the significance of this?

Comment: second column is tbl.sample_value not ctr.sample_value

Comment: read this http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/cursor_for.php or this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `sample_id` is retrieved from each row in the **cursor for loop**. It is a **row-by-row** operation, a.k.a. **slow-by-slow**. Although, a **cursor for loop** is implicitly treated as `bulk collect limit 100`, you could still improve the performance by using it along with **FORALL** statement.

Let's see a small example of a **cursor for loop** similar to your code:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    cnt NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR i IN
  5    (SELECT DISTINCT deptno FROM emp
  6    )
  7    LOOP
  8      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt FROM emp WHERE deptno = i.deptno;
  9      dbms_output.put_line('Count of deptno '||i.deptno||' is '||cnt);
 10    END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /
Count of deptno 30 is 6
Count of deptno 20 is 5
Count of deptno 10 is 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thank you, It helped me understand the concept :)

Comment: @PratikDhole You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!